# Foreman running guard with color ouput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, foreman

I can run guard from within my foreman procfile - but the output is not as colorful as I'd like.  The only color I see in my output is from Foreman...

I want to have a guardfile that manages rspec, cucumber and jasmine - AND have that nice color  output when those tests run.

It would seem as if foreman ignores guard file settings. Any idea how to change that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the --tty option to your rspec guard cli:

```
guard "rspec", :version => 2, :cli => "--tty ...other options..."
```

Comment: Many thanks! This was very helpful. It turned out it's not enough when using guard-rspec to use just --color, you (at least I saw this) MUST specify --tty also. This is on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

For version 4.5.0 of `guard-rspec` the following worked for me

```
guard :rspec, cmd_additional_args: "--tty", cmd: ...other...
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Even simpler, in Guardfile do

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "rspec --force-color"

# In case you do --profile and dot in regular .rspec, you may want to override further:
guard :rspec, cmd: "rspec --force-color --no-profile --format documentation"
```

/EDIT

I struggled with this and got it running with RSpec 3.8, rails 5.2 and foreman 0.64

Two configs must be done to make it work.

```
# In .rspec, add
--color

# In Guardfile, change to
guard :rspec, cmd: "rspec --tty" do
```

It's confusing why --color and tty are needed, the official rspec documentation says that both tty and color are default enabled.

Endnote: if you are doing this, running guard with foreman, it tells me a lot about what kind of developer you are. Say no more ;)