# foreman: preserve colorized output for commands in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I have `Procfile` which starts a rails server and a gulp watch task. Run independently, these tasks format their output with colors. Inside Foreman, they don't.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154982/foreman-running-guard-with-color-ouput), I am guessing that I will need to pass arguments to `rails s` and `gulp` for the colors to be kept. Is that true, or is it possible with an argument to foreman?

If it's not, what arguments would I pass to rails and gulp for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
var colors = require('colors');
colors.enabled = true;

// Or if you're using chalk
var chalk = require('chalk');
chalk.enabled = true;
```